# DropDownList empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I want DropDownList helper to generate an empty  Drop Down List with specific id name so that I use JQuery latter to put some data in it. How I can do that?

Comment: BTW one way of doing this is to add options in drop down on page load using jQuery

Comment: If you are using the data using jQuery, why not simply write a Html Select element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a custom helper

```
public static IHtmlString EmptyDropDownList(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
{
   return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<select id=\"{0}\"></select>", id));
}
```

usage :

```
@Html.EmptyDropDownList("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

The DropDownList is a ListControl. Its item members are also controls. If you add values to this via the frontend, the server will detect a tampering with the ViewState.

If you want to add values from the frontend use the good old html `<select>`